# How can I run my Regex in VSCode correctly?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to match log statements with strings that start with capital letters so I can make the capital letter lowercase. How can I do this? VSCode is saying my regex is invalid.

Attempt:
`.*\.([Dd]ebug|[Ii]nfo|[Ww]arn)\(\"([A-Z])`

[image]

Comment: The escape before the `"` is not needed and apparently the vscode regex engine doesn't like it.

Comment: Ah cool, thanks Mark. Any ideas on replacing just the upper with lowercase?
.*\.([Dd]ebug|[Ii]nfo|[Ww]arn)\("([A-Z]) matches, but \l$2 is removing everything up to the lowercase character

Comment: Ah, looks like `$1("\l$3` did the trick